# Show all data in Log

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
queryBuilder.setTables(Test.TEST_TABLE_NAME);

mCursor = queryBuilder.query(mDB, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

This working good with Adapter, but how can i make simple foreach and show data in Log.i?

My table TEST have two field: **name** and **title**.

Comment: DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: call DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor

Answer (score 0):

Use some [dumpCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursor%28android.database.Cursor,%20java.io.PrintStream%29) variant:

```
mCursor = ...;
Log.i(TAG, DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(mCursor));
```